# Oracle Select Query

Tags: oracle10g

How can I perform a select operation on two fields and view them as a single field?

ex:

I have a customer table that holds the customers data, I want to select both last_name and first_name (two different fields) and want to view them like this, "last_name, first_name"

using the oracle command not using any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT '"' || last_name || ',' || first_name || '"' from table
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT last_name || ', ' || first_name full_name
  FROM tbl
```